# ZF2 how to get entity Manager from outside of controller

Tags: zend-framework2

we can access entity manager within controller using `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');`

but how can we access entity manager singleton instance in rest of the project in Zendframework 2.

Comment: Just a Question, since you're talking about the Doctrine ORM, are you having troubles getting the entityManager down to your fieldset levels? :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The 'right' way to do it is use a factory to inject the entity manager into any classes that need it. Classes, other than factories, shouldn't really be aware of the ServiceLocator. So, your module config would look like this:

```
 'controllers' => array(
     'factories' => array(
          'mycontroller' => 'My\Namespace\MyControllerFactory'
     )
 )
```

Then your factory class would look something like this:

```
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class MyControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $serviceLocator = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();

        $myController = new MyController;
        $myController->setEntityManager(
            $serviceLocator->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default')
        );

        return $myController;
    }
}
```

Follow the same pattern for any other classes that need to consume the entity manager.

If, you have lots and lots of classes that consume the entity manager, you might want to consider adding your own Initalizer to the SerivceManager that will inject the entity manager without the need for a factory.

Comment: I like your last suggestion. He can create an 'EntityManagerAwareInterface' and have the ServiceLocator automatically inject it to any classes that implement it. I think they mention this on the README of the doctrine-orm-module page all the way at the bottom. It's coming soon.

Comment: Yeah, you want to be careful with Initalizers - they are run every time an object is fetched from the ServiceManager. If you stack the ServiceManager with Initalizers that are not used much, you are just slowing things down, which is why I only suggest it if the entity manager is needed in lots of classes.

Comment: good point on that performance comment. Thanks for helping me see that.