# init method in zf2 controller

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

In Zendframework 1 we use `init()` method for initialize stuff in controller. I saw that this is taken out from zenframework 2. Why? and what is the best way to achieve same thing in zf 2. I am upgrading my previous project developed in zf1 and I can see things has changed a lot in zf2 as compare to zf1.

Is there anyother change in zf2, they way we use other methods such as `preDispatch()` and `postDispatch()` in zf1?

Anyone has gone through this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In zf2 controllers are instantated by the ControllerLoader, which is a subclass of the ServiceManager. If you need to initalize a controller, either use a Factory, or `__construct`. Use `__construct` for simpile initalizations, and use a Factory if the controller consumes other objects that need to be injected.

`preDispatch` and `postDispatch` are also gone in favour of the new events system. To get the same result in zf2, register event handlers for the `disptach` and `render` events. For a full list of mvc envents see http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/a-list-of-zf2-events/

Also, take a look here for an example of setting up a controller factory [ZF2 how to get entity Manager from outside of controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866504/zf2-how-to-get-entity-manager-from-outside-of-controller)

Comment: In addition to akrabats full list of events a blog of Matthew W.O'Phinney http://mwop.net/blog/2012-07-30-the-new-init.html

Comment: Thanks sam, this link is really helpful.

Answer (score 8):

I think you can drop this into a controller and it will work.

```
public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $e)
```

Comment: this is the answer i liked.

Comment: Jesus thanks, why is everything so convoluted in ZF2

Answer (score 0):

Since OP mentions `postDispatch`, it's worth noting that `__destruct` now works in a similar manner. One big difference, though, is that execution cannot be prevented (e.g. through `exit;`) turing tear-down of the Object.